# I can't see my project in gitweb. How do you configure gitweb properly?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration, gitolite, gitweb

**Goal: To see my project in the gitweb webpage.**

I have git+gitolite+gitweb installed. My gitolite.conf file is:

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   ADMINUSER

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all

repo    PROJECT1
        RW+     =   USER1
        RW+     =   USER2
        R       =   gitweb
```

When I go to my server's http://server/gitweb/gitweb.cgi but the only projects that I can see are:

- testing.git

On the server running gitolite. The /home/git/projects.list file has:

```
PROJECT1.git
```

**How do I get PROJECT1 to show up when I go to the gitweb URL?**

Comment: I thought adding `R = gitweb` for PROJECT1 would make PROJECT1 show up on the gitweb project list... but I still only see testing.git.

Comment: Given that my gitolite works, I think ssh is configured properly. (I have gitolite installed in the user "git"'s home directory.)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your gitweb.conf has follow lines.

```
$projectroot = "/home/git/repositories"; 
$projects_list = "/home/git/projects.list";
```

change that path to yours. I had same problem because I dont have the second line. So my repo show randomly on web.

Answer (score 1):

You normally only need to give read access to gitweb: see [specifying gitweb and daemon access](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/confother_.html#gwd)

> To make a repo or repo group accessible via "`git daemon`", just give read permission to the special user "`daemon`".
>   Similarly, give read permission to `gitweb` to allow the `gitweb` CGI to show the repo.
>   Something like this:

```
repo    foo bar baz
    R   =   gitweb daemon
```

> This gives you a quick way to offer multiple repos up for gitweb and/or daemon access.

You can also simply add a description to your project to make it visible:

```
repo    PROJECT1
        PROJECT1 = "description for PROJECT1"
        RW+     =   USER1
        RW+     =   USER2
```

For the rest, make sure your [gitolite+gitweb+ssh+http-backend setup](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ggshb.html) follows the documentation.

Comment: In my gitolite configuration I do have `R = gitweb` already but gitweb doesn't show PROJECT1. Gitweb only shows PROJECT1 when I give PROJECT1 `R = @all`.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith `R = gitweb` isn't enough. Do you also have `RW+     =   USER1`? (ie another rule for other users)

Comment: In my gitolite.conf for PROJECT1 I do have `RW+ = USER1`.

Comment: Given that I have `R = gitweb` but gitweb doesn't show PROJECT1, doesn't that mean my http/apache is not configured properly?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: I suspect so. Time to double-check http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ggshb.html. If somehow the identification for USER1 isn't properly passed to Gitolite, gitweb won't display the site.

Comment: I will look into the ggshb.html website link you gave. But I am confused what does the USER1 have to do with my gitweb configuration?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith because the `R = gitweb` is only there to list all projects that gitweb can *potentially* display. But it won't display the ones where you ('USER1') have no 'R' rights.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be a group ownership issue. From previously using ssh access, I had the group ownership of the repos set to an internal developer group rather than git. Once I ran:

```
chown -R git:git /home/git/repositories
```

All repos showed up with the conf file using:

```
$projects_list = $projectroot;
```